# The definition of differentiable function between smooth manifolds is independent of the charts

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $ M $ and $ N $ be differentiable manifolds, and let $ f\colon M\to N $ be a function from their underlying sets. Let's call $ f $ *differentiable* if for every point $ x\in M $ and for every chart $ (V,\psi) $ on $ V $ such that $ f(x)\in V $ there exists a chart $ (U,\phi) $ on $ M $ such that $ f(U)\subset V $ and such that the composite $ f_{\psi\phi} $ (from now on, the *local representative* of $ f $ with respect to the given charts) of the maps
$$
\phi(U)\xrightarrow{\phi^{-1}} U\xrightarrow{f{\restriction_U^V}} V \xrightarrow{\psi} \psi(V)
$$
where $ f{\restriction_U^V} $ is the restriction of $ f $ in domain and in codomain to $ U $ and $ V $ respectively, is of class $ C^\infty $.

I would like to to show that if $ f $ is any function from $ M $ to $ N $ and $ (U,\phi) $, $ (U^\prime,\phi^\prime) $ and $ (V,\psi) $, $ (V^\prime,\psi^\prime) $ are two pair of charts on $ M $ and on $ N $ respectively such that $ f(U)\subset V $ and $ f(U^\prime)\subset V^\prime $, then the local representative $ f_{\psi\phi} $ of $ f $ with respect to $ (U,\phi) $ and $ (V,\psi) $ is a $ C^\infty $ mapping if and only if so it is $ f_{\psi^\prime,\phi^\prime} $.

The statement above appears without proof in Proposition 1.4.7 in "Foundations of Mechanics" by R. Abraham and J. E. Marsden.

I'm stuck. Moreover, I'm not sure if we should take $ f $ to be differentiable to this claim to be true, or if it holds for any $ f $.

Comment: Say you got two overlapping charts. What regularity has the transition map?

Comment: I did not show my attempts, but I was confused by the fact that (say) the two charts $ (U,\phi) $ and $ (U^\prime,\phi^\prime) $ may not overlap. If they do, then I can find a map $ \phi^\prime(U\cap U^\prime)\to \psi^\prime(V\cap V^\prime) $ by composing with $ f $ (after some surgery on the domains and codomains), and this map is $ C^\infty $. But the function I obtain in this way is not $ f_{\psi^\prime\phi^\prime} $ (maybe only a restriction).

Comment: Checking differentiability is a local question. Each point is contained in some chart. If it's only one, then no problem. If it's in more than one, then the overlap condition tells you that it is differentiable on some (small) open set containing the point.

Comment: If I understood your comment correctly, I should prove that (assuming $ f_{\psi\phi} $ is $ C^\infty $) given a point $ y\in \phi^\prime(U^\prime) $ there is an open set containing $ y $ where $ f_{\psi^\prime\phi^\prime} $ is $ C^\infty $. Okay, take $ y\in \phi^\prime(U^\prime) $ and let $ x = {(\phi^\prime)}^{-1}(y) $. There is a chart $ (W,\chi) $ such that $ x\in W $, i.e. such that $ y\in \phi^\prime(U\cap W) $. But then?